# Do links to an account work after it's merged to another?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, merge-accounts, short-links

I want to [merge two accounts of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18233/248268) but I worry about incoming links: what happens to them? Will I break the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will. I just merged a [recent and more active account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4145951/nemo) into an [older mostly inactive one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333493/nemo). Now the first link just gives a 404.

I don't know whether the absence of redirects is intentional or just a missing feature. Looks like the merged account is entirely deleted.

Links won't break to things which don't change their IDs, though. For example a [tag filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/116580/mediawiki) ID/URL doesn't depend on the account ID.

When merging accounts, you may want to try to make sure an account with many incoming links is not deleted. I don't know if you can choose, though: perhaps you have to ask merge from the account you want to delete, or perhaps the oldest account is always preserved no matter what.

Comment: You can ask which to merge. Why is this Community Wiki?

Comment: @Tim, thanks. How? It's CW because this answer is intended to collect facts, but I wasn't done collecting all facts so I want it to be mercilessly edited. :)

Comment: Fair enough. In the contact email I believe you specify which to merge :)

Comment: @Tim, I had no such option in the email, which was identical to both accounts: «Hello,  We received your request to merge the following Stack Overflow accounts:  http://stackoverflow.com/users/1333493/nemo  http://stackoverflow.com/users/4145951/nemo  Before we can merge, we need to confirm that you own both of these accounts. To confirm ownership of Nemo, click the link below:» I *think* there was no such option in the form either, but I wouldn't swear it.