# Are visits to permalinks by an account still attributed to it after it's merged?

Tags: support, merge-accounts, permalink, publicity-badges

[Account 4145951](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4145951/nemo) was merged into [account 1333493](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333493/nemo). Instead of a permalink with [trailing /4145951](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386829/4145951), the user will now be offered a [trailing /1333493](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386829/1333493) by the "share" link / "share a link to this answer" dialog.

If someone clicks lingering links with the deleted user ID, are such visits still "attributed" to the surviving account, e.g. for the sake of publicity badges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why does it matter? Are you a badge whore, Nemo?

Anyway, I don't know; let's hope someone does and posts a better answer. However, from the [fate of profile links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/255854/248268) (404) it seems the merged account gets entirely deleted. If the profile doesn't redirect, it's unlikely that visits attribution is redirected.

On the bright side, you have a different ID on each StackExchange site (e.g. 248268 here on MSE for that SO account). On sites where there were no conflicting accounts, the global account merge results in no user ID changes and everything continues to work smoothly.